# Ending off a script with a bit of spice

Tags: python-2.7

So let's say I have a python script, and it runs nicely without errors and all is well in the world. Now is there some kind of way to have a final line like this:

```
if (code runs without errors):
    print "Hurray! It worked!"
```

EDIT: My appologies, I just didn't include my code because it's about 70 lines. It involves image manipulation, so the last couple lines involve saving using the nipy module, as so:

```
nipy.save_image(img, 'img.nii.gz')
```

However I think you guys need much more info which would complicate things. I'll just take the advice of most of you here and just print "Hurray! It worked!" at the very end. Thanks guys

Comment: yes there is, what's your code

Comment: if an error occurs outside a try/except the script would not arrive at the end,I think, `print "Hurray"` in the last line should be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.  Put that statement last.  If that's not an option, you should probably rethink your code's structure (but without more information about that we can't help you).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the script to execute without errors you can just put the print statement at the bottom of the script.  If you want to check to see if something loaded correctly we need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want that to print after the program runs through, append the `print` statement to the end of your file. Doing this will print the text only if no other errors occurred. However, this assumes that you do not do anything with explicit error handling (`try` and `except` blocks). If you do deal with error handling, then you will likely have to maintain a counter (or a `bool`, I prefer counters because you can tell exactly how many errors occurred) when an error has occurred, then check that counter before you `print` out the text. For example:

```
error_counter=0
try:
    raise ValueError           #This will raise the value error
except ValueError:
    error_counter+=1           #Incriment the error_counter to make sure the final print statement does not execute

if error_counter == 0:         #Check if an error occurred. The error did occur, so it skips the print statement.
    print "Hurray! It worked!"
```